# Search d3 force directed graph

Tags: d3.js

I have already created a force layout with images as nodes and mouse over text.

However, now I am trying to add the ability to search for a specific node using a text box and a search button. When a user searches for text I would like to select the matching node and its connections. The matched node and connections would change color. My code is below, but my search function is not working as intended. How do I change this code to get the desired behavior?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>

     .link {
     stroke: #777;
     stroke-opacity: 0.3;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
     }

      .node circle {
      fill: #ccc;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }

      .node text {
         fill: red;
      display: none;
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      }

     .node:hover circle {
     fill: #000; 
     }

    .node:hover text {
    display: inline;
    }

    .cell {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
    }

     </style>
    <body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <div>
    <input id="targetNode" name="targetNode" type="text" value="Enter the text" />
    <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
    </div>
    <script>

    var width =1500,
    height = 650

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.1)
    .charge(-500)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .size([width, height]);

    d3.json("miserables1.json", function(error, json) {
     if (error) throw error;
    force
    .nodes(json.nodes)
    .links(json.links)
    .start();

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(json.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
     .call(force.drag);

    node.append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {

    return d.imagen;

     })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
     return -25;
     })
     .attr("y", function(d) {
      return -25;
     })
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", 50)
    .append("title")
    .text(function(d){ return d.name });


    function search() {

    var userInput = document.getElementById("targetNode"); 
    var theNode = d3.select("#c"+userInput.value);
    return theNode;

    }

    function linkToNodes() {
    force.links().forEach(function(link) {
    linkedByIndex[link.source.index + "," + link.target.index] = 1;
    });
    }

    function neighboring(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index]    || a.index == b.index;
    }



    force.on("tick", function() {

    link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
     return d.source.x;
     })
     .attr("y1", function(d) {
     return d.source.y;
     })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
     return d.target.y;
     });
    node
   .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    });
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you intend do happen when the user clicks search.  Your search function tries to select `"#c" + userInput.value`, but I can't see anything on the page with that ID. If your data has a name field that you want it to be searchable on then you could set the id of each node to that name with the following:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("id", d => "c" + d.name) // setting ID here
    .attr("class", "node")
         .call(force.drag);
```

This would allow your search function to get a reference to the node, but currently it is just returning it, and the calling function isn't going to do anything with that reference, if you want to highlight that that node as been selected you should put some code in here to do that, e.g:

```
function search() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("targetNode"); 
    var theNode = d3.select("#c"+userInput.value);

    theNode.style("color", "red");
}
```

Comment: The above code is giving an error as Search function is not defined. Where i am missing this